# PSR4 Composer Autoloading namespaces

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I've been having a little play around with some `Composer` autoloading and i'm getting some issues so the directory structure is

```
index.php
app/
   helpers/
          router.php
vendor/
   composer/
          /*usual files*/
   autoload.php
```

Inside my `composer.json` I have the following

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
```

Inside my `index.php` I have

```
<?php
// Autoload our namespaces
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Helpers\Router;
$route = new Router;
```

Getting the following error

`Fatal error: Class 'App\Helpers\Router' not found in /var/www/public/index.php on line 6`

I have tried a few different things to try and get it working but i'm unsure where i'm going wrong. This is my first time looking into autoloading using Composer outside of a framework so would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PSR-4 is case sensitive. The structure has to be `app/Helpers/Router.php` or better App with capital A.

> All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion.
>
> The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.
>
> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: Additional tip: If you've just updated your autoload config in composer.json you can get composer to only regenerate the autoload config with `composer dumpautoload` rather than waiting for `composer update` to update its package lists for no raisin.

Comment: Thanks it was a mixture of case sensitivity and file name spaces being a little squiffy. Thanks all you've really helped out!